# Input names display list view using array

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I am currently working on my project in android studio where I want to input names on an EditView from the bottomSheet and then displays it on the screen. I'm already at the MainActivity but dont know how to put it in an Array. I hope someone can help me.
...
This is from my ListAdapter.java file
...

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>{

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User>){
    super(context,R.layout.list_item,userArrayList);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    User user = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null){

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

    }

    TextView tlTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tl_title);
    TextView prProf = convertView.findViewById(R.id.pr_prof);
    TextView dpDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_date);

    tlTitle.setText(user.tl_title);
    prProf.setText(user.pr_prof);
    dpDate.setText(user.dp_date);
```

...
And this is from my MainActivity.java
...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Initialize Variable
ImageButton btShow;
ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String tl_title = new String();
    //or
    String[] tl_title = username.getText(R.id.tl_title);
```

...
I still have a lot of files for my xml, If I encounter something that I get confused of, I hope someone can patiently accept as I ask too many questions. Thank you.

Comment: Help us, help you. What have you tried so far? Please be noted that stackoverflow is not a free coding service, questions like this can get downvoted out of existence very quickly if you haven't shown any effort. 

Comment: Sorry if my question seemed immature. I actually have made something already but I am stuck at the Array part or String. I am just confused how to position it in my mainactivity and want some guidance on how to use it properly.

Comment: If you could provide us with some code, I'm sure that will get a lot more attention for feedback.

Comment: Okay, I was actually using my phone when I made this post. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Use recycler view instead of ArrayAdapter, pass the List to recycler view adapter, add the String to the list which is taken from EditText, call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thank you. Is it the one from my ListAdapter.java? I'm sorry, I'm not really good at java, but I'm trying my best to learn.

Comment: Instead of using `ArrayAdapter`, you can use RecyclerView. with the help of Recyclerview you can easily perform add/delete operation.